# Where is "Product Configuration" for Eclipse Mars to config plugin locations?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to share plugins among different eclipse instances. I found this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-manage/) about changing eclipse plugin location. It use the `Help > Software Updates > Manager Configuration` to do that. But I can't find in latest `eclipse mars`. Where is it? Or is this approach deprecated?

Comment: That article is talking about the old Eclipse update system. It has been completely replaced by the 'p2' system in the last several releases of Eclipse.

Comment: Thx. How to config plugin locations with p2 then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[p2 Bundle Pooling](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started#Bundle_pooling), which is the capability you're looking for, is not easy to work with "by hand," it's really intended to be used by tools, not humans (in my opinion). The good news is that you can use the [Eclipse Installer (Oomph)](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php?show_instructions=TRUE) and [tell it to use bundle pooling](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.oomph.setup.doc%2Fhtml%2Fconcepts%2FDocBundlePool.html).